# How to create Portable Workspace in TFS like SVN?

Tags: svn, tfs

In SVN I checkout the code on Removable HDD and able to connect to any other machine & checkin & get latest code. Just by entering Username & Password.

TFS however loses track of local changes.

> Was wondering if it is possible to checkout the code from TFS into
>   portable HDD, connect to other PC and check-in the code from there.

I tried searching a lot, but could not find right references. I am hopeful that it must be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS tracks workspaces, files and file states by computer name and workspace name.  To be able to keep working on different physical computers, you should at lease match below conditions:

- use always the same drive name ( you could change it in computer
  management)
- After connecting on new computer, need to update the computer name of workspace:

  ```
  tf workspaces /updateComputerName:MyOldComputerName /s:http://MyTFServer:8080
  ```

  It will move workspace to your current computer

More details about the tf command please refer: **[Workspaces Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/workspaces-command)**